# Can I redraw only part of a scene in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, composition, scene

I have a scene composed of many objects. Most of the objects are static, but some objects move. When a move happens it seems like I have to redraw the whole scene. It is possible for me to express some kind of compositing of the scene and redraw only some of the components of the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render the static parts to a FBO, blit that as needed to the framebuffer, and render dynamic objects on top.